# Distance matrix in QGIS shows distance zero to all points

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I'm using QGIS version 3.4.2-Madeira. I have a point layer with 96 points in Germany and I want to calculate the 3 nearest neighbors of every point. I know this can be done with the Distance matrix function using the same layer as input and target, but I always get a distance of zero between all points which is definitely not correct. I tried the same with the QGIS Tutorial datasets to calculate the distance between two different point layers, that worked well.

Does anybody has an idea where the problem is?

Comment: Check the coordinate system of the points layer. Is it unprojected? If so, try projecting it to a projected coordinate system and do it again.

Comment: It is EPSG: 4326 and the points are shown correctly on the map. My project coordinate system is the EPSG 3395 World Mercator

Comment: this may possibly help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211038/how-does-qgis-calculate-distances-when-the-data-is-not-projected-wgs84